# random forest prediction model

Tags: r, random-forest, prediction

I am trying to build a random forest model for prices prediction problem. I have went through the following steps:

1) split the data into 3 sets train, test and valid (it is required to split into 3 sets not only train and test)

```
set.seed(1234)
assignment <- sample(1:3, size = nrow(train), prob = c(0.7, 0.15, 0.15), replace = TRUE) 
#Create a train, validation and tests from the train data
train_train <- train[assignment == 1, ]  
train_valid <- train[assignment == 2, ]  
train_test <- train[assignment == 3, ]
```

2) I have built the model with x and y being from the train set

```
fit_rf_train <- train(x = train_train[, -which(names(train_train) %in% 
c("Item_Identifier", "Item_Outlet_Sales"))], 
                y = train_train$Item_Outlet_Sales,
                method = "ranger",
                metric = "RMSE",
                tuneGrid = expand.grid(
                  .mtry = 6,
                  .splitrule = "variance",
                  .min.node.size = c(10,15,20)),
                trControl = trControl,
                importance = "permutation",
                num.trees = 350)
```

I have the following screenshot for model output on the same train data:

[image: Model output on train data]

3) Using predict function I used the model with the two other data sets, valid and test using the following line of code:

```
prediction_test <- predict(fit_rf_train, train_test)
prediction_valid <- predict(fit_rf_train, train_valid)
```

My question is how can I measure the performance of the model on the un seen data (test and valid)?

Comment: Which package are you using? How can you measure the performance? I think by using the RMSE as you chose that as your metric. The lower, the better. `caret::RMSE` assuming you're using `caret`

Comment: Caret package. Yes I know I will be using RMSE. But I mean which function to use in order to print me the performance of predict function. I mean using this line print(fit_rf_train) I could see the RMSE value on the train set now how can I do it with predict.

Comment: How would you do it for a classification? You use `confusionMatrix.` Now instead, you're using `RMSE()`.Type `?RMSE` you'll see several options.

Comment: If I type RMSE(prediction_test) I would get this error: argument "obs" is missing, with no default. Should I use the train data as the value of obs argument?

Comment: I have no access to `train`. Please add a `dput` of `train`

Comment: Train is the data set that I have splitted it into 3: train_train, train_valid, train_test. It contains the target variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to stick with `caret`, then you can do the following:

```
library(caret)
trainda<-createDataPartition(iris$Sepal.Length,p=0.8,list=F)
valid_da<-iris[-trainda,]
trainda<-iris[trainda,]
ctrl<-trainControl(method="cv",number=5)
set.seed(233)
m<-train(Sepal.Length~.,data=trainda,method="rf",metric="RMSE",trControl = ctrl,verbose=F)
m1<-predict(m,valid_da)
RMSE(m1,valid_da$Sepal.Length)
```

Result:

```
[1] 0.3499783
```

Comment: Great, thanks! I want also to ask is ir right that I build the model only on the train data (the 80% of the whole data) and then test it against the other two sets or I should have built it on the whole data?

Comment: I think it's ok. Sometimes you can "give" the model more data in the training phase to improve the "accuracy" although that comes with a bit of bias and/or fitting issues.

Comment: Thank you very much! one last question: I have a reduced RMSE value with the other two data sets. test RMSE: 1.909679 | valid RMSE: 1.928796 Which is better than that of the train data set what can we say about this?

Comment: I cannot be sure without knowing what the actual data looks like. In any case it looks ok.

Comment: That's right, I think I should work on this, I would appreciate any suggestions!

Comment: I would suggest looking at some feature engineering or look at the feature importance plots and see which are the most important features and look at how models perform with or without those features. You can use `varImp(m)` for the above example if you have used `importance=T` for the training(`m`)

Comment: Pleese I just need to know what is a similar function to calculate R-squared value?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188517/discussion-between-user233531-and-nelsongon).